# How to Overcome "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" Problem Newtonsoft Jsonconvert.SerializeObject

Tags: vb.net, json.net

Hi there I have the following code:

```
      Public Overloads Function GetJson(ByVal destination As PathDefinition) As String
           Dim chunk As DestinationItemList = Nothing
           If destination.Name = "PI" Then
                chunk = _chunk
           Else
                'Translate chunk to InfluxCompatible object
                '<Placeholder>
           End If
           Try
                Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chunk)
           Catch ex As Exception
                Throw
           End Try
      End Function
```

Which on the face of it appears pretty simple to serialize a list of the following object:

```
 Public Class Destinationtem
      Private _tagAttribute As String
      Private _tagRef As String
      Private _tagName As String
      Private _timeStamp As String
      Private _quality As String
      Private _value As String
      Private _serverName As String
End Class
```

For brevity I have ommitted the getters and setters.  The GetJson function is called from within:

```
Public Overloads Async Sub ProcessData()
   Dim cnt As Long
   Dim jsonString As String
   Dim destinationItem As Destinationtem
   Dim tagRef As String
   Dim token As String

   Try
        _oldDestinationItem = New Destinationtem
        _logger.SendLog("Processing data - " & _lvItems.Count & " records.", LogLevel.Trace)
        'Do until we have no more items to process
        Do While _lastCnt < _lvItems.Count - 1
             Try
                  'Get the next chunk of data
                  GetChunk()
                  If _chunk IsNot Nothing Then
                       If _chunk.Count > 0 Then
                            'If export tags is switched  on then export the tags
                            If _exportTagPath <> "" Then
                                 If _tagsForExport Is Nothing Then
                                      _tagsForExport = New DestinationItemList
                                 End If
                                 'For each entry in the chunk
                                 For Each destinationItem In _chunk
                                      tagRef = destinationItem.TagRef
                                      'Then add to the  list of tags to export
                                      'if the tag is not already in the list
                                      If _tagsForExport.Find(Function(p) 
p.TagRef = tagRef) Is Nothing Then
                                           'Add the item
                                           _tagsForExport.Add(destinationItem)
                                      End If
                                 Next destinationItem
                            End If
                            'Send the data to the destinations
                            For Each destination In _destinations
                                 'If this is the client for obtaining a token then get the token
                                 If destination.Name.ToUpper.IndexOf("TOKEN") <> -1 Then
                                      _token = Await GetToken(destination.HttpClient, destination.AuthInfo, destination.Path)
                                 Else
                                      ***jsonString = GetJson(destination)***
                                      Send(destination.HttpClient, jsonString, destination.Path)
                                 End If
                            Next
                       End If
                  End If
             Catch ex As MissingItemException
                  _logger.SendLog("The transformer identified by ID = '" & _lvItems(_lastCnt).TransformerId & "' was not found", LogLevel.Trace)
             End Try
        Loop
        _logger.SendLog("Number of records processed -  " & _lvItems.Count & " records.", LogLevel.Info)
   Catch ex As Exception
        _logger.SendLog("LV Data Loader encountered an exception whilst processing the data", LogLevel.Error, ex)
        Throw
   Finally
        'if export tags is true then save and close the file and dispose of the object
        _chunk.CloseFile()
   End Try

End Sub
```

I don't believe that I am modifying the collection (chunk) that is getting passed to GetJson, but I keep getting the 'System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.' error.

Original post edited to include stack trace as requested in Comments along with the code that generates the IEnumerable object referenced in the code:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value)
   at SPEN.LVDataLoader.ImportJson.GetJson(PathDefinition destination) in C:\_VSSWorkArea\LVDataLoader\LVDataLoader\ImportJson.vb:line 1136
   at SPEN.LVDataLoader.ImportJson.VB$StateMachine_199_ProcessData.MoveNext() in C:\_VSSWorkArea\LVDataLoader\LVDataLoader\ImportJson.vb:line 871

 Public Sub GetDestinations()

      Dim dst As PathDefinition
      Dim dstCnt As Integer


      Try

           'Get the number of source from the app.config file
           dstCnt = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Destinations")

           'For each destination  specified in the config file
           For cnt = 0 To dstCnt - 1
                dst = New PathDefinition
                dst.Active = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DestinationActive" & cnt)
                If dst.Active Then
                     dst.Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DestinationName" & cnt)
                     dst.AuthInfo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AuthInfo" & cnt)
                     dst.BaseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DestinationBaseAddress" & cnt)
                     dst.Token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DestinationTokenUrl" & cnt)
                     dst.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DestinationUrl" & cnt)
                     dst.HttpClient = GetHttpClient(dst)
                     _destinations.Add(dst)
                End If
           Next
      Catch ex As Exception
           _logger.SendLog("LVDataLoader.GetDestinations", NLog.LogLevel.Error, ex)
           Throw
      Finally
      End Try
 End Sub


'Send the data to the destinations

For Each destination In _destinations
     'If this is the client for obtaining a token then get the token
     If destination.Name.ToUpper.IndexOf("TOKEN") <> -1 Then
          _token = Await GetToken(destination.HttpClient, destination.AuthInfo, destination.Path)
     Else
          jsonString = GetJson(destination)
          Send(destination.HttpClient, jsonString, destination.Path)
     End If
Next
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: It's generally the subject of a For Each loop that is being modified when that error occurs. It's not immediately obvious that that's the case here though. Please provide the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Where is     GetChunk() code? and where  _chunk is defined?

Comment: Where EXACTLY is the error?

Comment: You need to look for anything that touches `_destinations`.  Something about what you're doing with `GetJson` is adding to or removing from that collection, which invalidates the enumerator.

Comment: I'd also look at any Task that could be updating `_destinations` from another thread. This could also be a Timer event. As Craig mentioned, check all your code for anything that modifies `_destinations` and consider using [SyncLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/synclock-statement) around it.

Comment: Re the comment from @ÉtienneLaneville I hadn't even thought about cross-thread issues.  If you have a cross-thread issue, though, you may be better off using a concurrent collection than just wrapping a lock around `_destinations`.

Comment: @Craig I've found locks to be helpful in understanding cross-threading issues in my own code so I recommend it for that reason.

Comment: For the record, if you have a collection that is being accessed on multiple threads then a concurrent collection is a good idea, but it won't do anything to prevent this issue, because it won't stop you modifying the collection on one thread while enumerating it on another. It will just prevent two operations on separate threads overlapping.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville - The _destinations list gets set on startup of the windows service that this code is a part of.  After it is set up it does not get altered, it is only ever referenced by subsequent code.

Comment: Ok, so I believe that the _destinations list might be a bit of a 'red herring', the error is initially generated in the GetJson sub, specifically:

Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_chunk)

Comment: @PaulJohnson If that's true, then something is going on with either the definition of `DestinationItemList` or with `chunk` itself.  Maybe there's something weird in the class definition where the iteration that the serializer is trying to do can somehow also modify the list, maybe there's an issue with the item to be serialized being shared so that you have a data race (serialization of list op racing against some other parallel op that modifies the list).

Comment: Ok...  So I've verified that the collection is indeed being altered and I've identified the code that is acting as a trigger for this, but I'm flumoxed as to why that would be.  Basically the call to get the token results in the _chunk being added to, but as far as I am aware there are no other instances of the code running in other threads for this to happen.  Original post added to.